# Iterative function to find start value to complete sequence in a certain number of steps

Tags: python, iteration

I'm currently trying to write a function in python that takes two values `goal` and `count` and iteratively searches for the value the function should start at in the amount of steps given by `count` until it finds a number either equal to or greater than `goal`.

This is what I have so far thanks to Sprizgola.

```
def find_start_forward(goal, count):
    """
    Function that iteratively searches forward from an initial
    start value of 0, computes the sequence until the last value is greater than or equal
    to the goal, and returns the start value of the sequence
    :param goal: The last number in the sequence
    :param count: How many steps to reach the goal
    :pre-conditions: goal >= 0 and count >= 0
    :return:
    """
    if count == 0:
        goal = goal
        return goal
    else:
        number = 0
        count = 0
        while True:
            number = number + 1
            goal_end = number * 2 + 5
            if goal_end >= goal:
                return number
            count += 1
```

Current output:

```
print(find_start_forward(100,1))
>> 48
print(find_start_forward(7,2))
>> 1
```

I want the final output to look something like these:

```
find_start_forward(100,1) It would find 48 is the first to follow the rules: * 2 + 5 is >= 100
48

find_start_forward(7,2) Finds what 2 steps from the start is >= 7
0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is returning `None` because it does not enter in the if clause before the loop end. I have modified the for loop with a while loop and added the count to each iteration:

```
def find_start_forward(goal, count):
    """
    Function that iteratively searches forward from an initial
    start value of 0, computes the sequence until the last value is greater than or equal
    to the goal, and returns the start value of the sequence
    :param goal: The last number in the sequence
    :param count: How many steps to reach the goal
    :pre-conditions: goal >= 0 and count >= 0
    :return:
    """
    if count == 0:
        goal = goal
        return goal
    else:
        start_value = 0

        while True:
            sequence_sum = start_value
            for i in range(count):
                goal_end = sequence_sum * 2 + 5
                if goal_end >= goal:
                    return start_value
                sequence_sum = goal_end

            start_value += 1
```

These are the ouput

```
print(find_start_forward(100,1))
>> 48
print(find_start_forward(7,2))
>> 0
print(find_start_forward(100,4))
>> 2
```

##### Edit 2:

Here it is! Basically i have created a nested loop: a while loop that keep increment the start value and the for loop that search for the number that complete the sequence in a value lesser than `count`. The last sentence of the text you [posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83gZv.jpg) help to understand the meaning of the problem.

Comment: While that does make it give outputs to both functions, the outputs I posted in my question are what they should return. I think it's simply because my attempt at it is wrong

Comment: I actually was just about to respond with that, thanks for the update. It works perfectly for  find_start_forward(100,1), but (7,2) should be 0 instead of 1. I'll update the question as your fix of my function is closer to what it should be

Comment: I think (7 ,2) should return 1 because the condition `goal_end = number * 2 + 5 > goal` is satisfied with `number = 2`, so that `count = 1` (first iteration `count=0`, second iteration `count=1`, so that `number=2` when `count =1`)

Comment: According to my book, when you type `find_start_forward(100,3)` it should return 9, but it returns 48 like `(100,1)` returns, and `find_start_forward(8,3)` returns 0 for example. The `count` is how many steps the function has to reach the `goal` number, so I want it to return the lowest start value of the sequence for each case.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the description if this helps; https://imgur.com/wnCrJYp I think it might have to do with not checking if the `count` exceeds the `count` specified when the function is called.